# Programmatically get the folder where my fortune files are stored

Tags: bash, file

I am trying to programmatically get the folder where my fortune files are stored, so that I can write a script to update my fortune cookies stored elsewhere. The output of `fortune -f` contains this information in the first line. So I attempted to do,

`fortune -f | head -n 1`

But this gives me the entire output as it is. So I tried

`head -n 1 < fortune -f`

Even this did not work as expected. Bash complained about an ambiguous redirect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why can't use `locate` or `find` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have `fortune` installed. But this should work:

```
$ fortune -f 2>&1 | head -1
```

My answer is based on below statement

> But this gives me the entire output as it is